# How to properly remove last space and last character with str_replace_all?

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to remove last space and last character for a column of strings.

Represented by an homogeneous atomic vector, string look like this:

```
dirty_string <- c('finance analyst i')
```

When I try this:

```
str_replace_all(dirty_string,  c('[[:space:]+$i]'=''))
```

It removes all spaces and all `i` characters

Output:

```
"fnanceanalyst"
```

Expected Output:

```
"finance analyst"
```

How could I declare a space before the last character inside `str_replace_all()`?

Comment: I assume you want to remove any trailing word, if not, you may simply use `str_replace(dirty_string, "\\s+i$", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
dirty_string <- c('finance analyst i')
str_replace(dirty_string, "\\s+\\w+$", "")
## => [1] "finance analyst"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/gcYEk4).

*Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `$` - end of string.

Note you do not need `str_replace_all`, as there is a single replacement operation involved, so `str_replace` will do.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ry1Joh/1).

Comment: FYI: If there is a chance of trailing whitespace, you may add `\s*` before `$`, `str_replace(dirty_string, "\\s+\\w+\\s*$", "")`

Answer (score 1):

Specify the last non-white space with `$` i.e end of the string.  Note that `str_remove` would be a better wrapper as we are replacing with blank

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(dirty_string, "\\s+\\S+$")
#[1] "finance analyst"
```

Details:

1. `\\s+` - one or more white space
2. `\\S+`- one or more non-white space
3. `$` - end of string

Answer (score 1):

base `R`

```
gsub("[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+$", "", dirty_string)
# [1] "finance analyst"
```

`stringr`

```
str_replace(dirty_string, "[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+$", "")
str_replace(dirty_string, "[[:space:]]+i$", "")
# [1] "finance analyst"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always, as you say, one whitespace and one character before string end, then this will do:

```
sub("(.*)(..)$", "\\1", dirty_string)
[1] "finance analyst"
```

Here you divide the string into two capturing groups `(...)`, the first of which takes everything before the two last characters, the second of which takes just these two last characters; in the replacement clause you recall only the first capturing group with `\\1`, thereby effectively removing what's in the second capturing group.

**EDIT**:

As noted in a comment by @Wiktor Stribiżew the second capture group is not needed:

```
sub("(.*)..$", "\\1", dirty_string)
```

Comment: You do not even need the second group, since we only capture what we want to keep. `sub("(.*)..$", "\\1", dirty_string)` will do.